# Как связать AJAX кнопку "Показать еще" и AJAX фильтр Wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Суть в том что когда я фильтрую записи кнопка "показать еще" работает на все записи. А как по клику по кнопке подгружать только те записи, которые выбраны в фильтре? В данном случае фильтр на категории товаров.

Обработчик кнопки:

```
<?php
function misha_my_load_more_scripts() {
 
  global $wp_query; 
 
  // In most cases it is already included on the page and this line can be removed
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
 
  // register our main script but do not enqueue it yet
  wp_register_script( 'my_loadmore', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/myloadmore.js', array('jquery') );
 
  // now the most interesting part
  // we have to pass parameters to myloadmore.js script but we can get the parameters values only in PHP
  // you can define variables directly in your HTML but I decided that the most proper way is wp_localize_script()
  wp_localize_script( 'my_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_params', array(
    'ajaxurl' => site_url() . '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', // WordPress AJAX
    'posts' => json_encode( $wp_query->query_vars ), // everything about your loop is here
    'current_page' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
    'max_page' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
  ) );
 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_loadmore' );
}
 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'misha_my_load_more_scripts' );

function misha_loadmore_ajax_handler(){
 
  $args = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST['query'] ), true );
  $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; // we need next page to be loaded
  $args['post_status'] = 'publish';
 
  // it is always better to use WP_Query but not here
  query_posts( $args );
 
  if( have_posts() ) :
        woocommerce_product_loop_start();
    // run the loop
    while( have_posts() ): the_post();
 
      // look into your theme code how the posts are inserted, but you can use your own HTML of course
      // do you remember? - my example is adapted for Twenty Seventeen theme
          wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
      // for the test purposes comment the line above and uncomment the below one
      // the_title();
 
 
    endwhile;
        woocommerce_product_loop_end();
  endif;
  die; // here we exit the script and even no wp_reset_query() required!
}
 
 
 
add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_ajax_handler'); // wp_ajax_{action}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_ajax_handler'); // wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}
```

Ajax кнопки:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    // use jQuery code inside this to avoid "$ is not defined" error
    $(".btn--more").click(function () {
        var button = $(this),
            data = {
                action: "loadmore",
                query: misha_loadmore_params.posts, // that's how we get params from wp_localize_script() function
                page: misha_loadmore_params.current_page,
            };

        $.ajax({
            // you can also use $.post here
            url: misha_loadmore_params.ajaxurl, // AJAX handler
            data: data,
            type: "POST",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                button.html('Загрузка... <svg class="icon icon-load icon-load--anim"><use xlink:href="#icon-load"></use></svg>'); // change the button text, you can also add a preloader image
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    button.html('Показать ещё <svg class="icon icon-load"><use xlink:href="#icon-load"></use></svg>').prev().after(data); // insert new posts
                    misha_loadmore_params.current_page++;

                    if (misha_loadmore_params.current_page == misha_loadmore_params.max_page) button.remove(); // if last page, remove the button

                    // you can also fire the "post-load" event here if you use a plugin that requires it
                    // $( document.body ).trigger( 'post-load' );
                } else {
                    button.remove(); // if no data, remove the button as well
                }
            },
        });
    });
});
```

Вывод кнопки:

```
global $wp_query; // you can remove this line if everything works for you

    // don't display the button if there are not enough posts
    if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 )
        echo '<div class="btn--more">Показать ещё <svg class="icon icon-load"><use xlink:href="#icon-load"></use></svg></div>'; // you can use <a> as well
    }
```

Обработчик фильтра:

```
function perviy_filter() {
  global $wp_query; 

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
                'field' => 'name',
                'terms' => 'exclude-from-catalog',
                'operator' => 'NOT IN',
            )
        ),
    );

    // Категории товаров
    $product_cats = ! empty( $_POST[ 'product_cats' ] ) && $_POST[ 'product_cats' ] ? $_POST [ 'product_cats' ] : array();
    
    if( $product_cats ) {
        $args['tax_query'][] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'terms' => $product_cats
        );
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST['term_id']);
    echo '</pre>';
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        endwhile;
    }


    die();
}
```

Ajax фильтра:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#ajax-filter").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const form = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: woocommerce_params.ajax_url,
            data: form.serialize(),
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                $(".site-main").block({
                    message: null,
                    overlayCSS: {
                        background: "#fff",
                        opacity: 0.3,
                    },
                });
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("ul.products").html(data);
                $(".site-main").unblock();
            },
        });
    });
    $('#ajax-filter input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
        $("#ajax-filter").submit();
    });
});
```

Форма фильтра

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="ajax-filter">
                <?php $product_categories = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'hide_empty' => true ) );
                if( $product_categories ) : ?>
                <ul class="category">
                    <?php foreach( $product_categories as $product_category ) : ?>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="product_cats[]" id="product-cat-<?php echo absint( $product_category->term_id ) ?>" value="<?php echo absint( $product_category->term_id ) ?>">
                        <label for="product-cat-<?php echo absint( $product_category->term_id ) ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $product_category->name ); ?></label>
                    </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="perviyfilter">
              </form>
```

Comment: При нажатии на кнопку "показать еще" делать проверку. Если фильтры не назначены выполнять обычный запрос по параметрам jquery, если же фильтры установлены, то посылать на сервер переменную в которой бы эта иформация смотрела б по другому циклу (учитывая текущую страниуц выдачи)... Тут нету простого ответа, но алгоритм вроде понятный.